# Scopus API -> All citations to publication

Tags: scopus

is it possible to get all citations to concrete publication (by scopus_id, doi ...) with Elsevier API?

I was trying do that, by all I can do, is get count of citations, but i need Authors annd Titles al least.

For example, if I wanna do:

```
https://api.elsevier.com/content/abstract/citations?pubmed_id=3472723&httpAccept=application/json&apiKey={myKey}
```

I get:

```
"{"service-error":{"status":{"statusCode":"AUTHENTICATION_ERROR","statusText":"Requestor configuration settings insufficient for access to this resource."}}}"
```

Is it possible to get what I want?

Thanks

Comment: You cant accept an answer to mark the question as resolved (if the answer was helpful). This will help future users as well.

Comment: Notice that while I'm indeed unable to explain the error you get, it would _not_ return you Authors and Titles, but just citations per year

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had same problem, but i found this solution:

Firstly you should have json with article data and article's 'eid'. Thus, you can find all citations of this article by next query:

```
"https://api.elsevier.com/content/search/scopus?query=refeid(" + str(article['eid']) + ')'
```

article is json data of this article

Also i had problem with keywords, and solution is:

Article json has article['prism:url'] parameter, and you can use it with keywords field, so you query to get keywords is:

```
article['prism:url'] + "?field=authkeywords"
```

Comment: Hi Mikhail, your solution works fine, however, it returns only the first `itemsPerPage` results and not the `totalresults`. For instance, an article with 108 citations returned only the first 25 results. Any idea how to overcome that?

Answer (score 1):

[Mikhail's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30510960/2858145) is the best way to reach your goal, since you need authors and titles of citing works.

But for those who come here searching for the specific error: it is due to the fact that the `https://api.elsevier.com/content/abstract/citations` API needs "specific permission from Elsevier", which means that you need to write to their Integration Support, explaining your use case and providing your API key.

(as explained to me via email by a member of the Integration Support itself)

Comment: Yeah, the reason in the specific permission. I tried to receive this permission. However, my dialog with them was finished on "We don't permit data-mining of Scopus". Therefore, I used that "lifehack" that is not convinient and not effective.

Answer (score 1):

Just bumped into the same problem. the interactive API of Scopus might help you a lot with this and similar issues.

How to proceed:

1. Visit https://dev.elsevier.com/scopus.html#!/Citations_Overview/CitationsOverview
   (If you are logged in and have an API key, the API key will automatically appear in the corresponding field)
2. Insert the doi of the article from which the citations are required in the appropriate field.
3. Get Request URL - here is an example: [https://api.elsevier.com/content/abstract/citations?doi=10.1287%2Fmnsc.42.4.541&apiKey={apiKey}&httpAccept=application%2Fjson](https://api.elsevier.com/content/abstract/citations?doi=10.1287%2Fmnsc.42.4.541&apiKey=%7BapiKey%7D&httpAccept=application%2Fjson)
   (don't forget to insert your apiKey in the curly brackets.

Hope this helps and makes things a lot easier!

Answer (score 0):

In case one cannot obtain "specific permission from Elsevier" to use their API in this manner, you can use the API of *OpenCitations* ([documentation here](https://opencitations.net/index/coci/api/v1)).

Use the URL `https://opencitations.net/index/coci/api/v1/citations/{DOI}`. The field name `citing` contains as values the DOIs of all publications that cite the `{DOI}`.

One example with three citations [here](https://opencitations.net/index/coci/api/v1/citations/10.1177/1369148118786043) (as of January 2021).